# Running java.exe as pre-build step in .NET Core/Standard fails with 9009

Tags: c#, build, .net-core, .net-standard

I am trying to run java.exe as a pre-build step in a C#-.NET Standard 2.0 project. The csproj file contains the following snippet:

```
<Target Name="Java" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="c:\Windows\System32\java.exe"/>
</Target>
```

(I simplified the command line for testing.) The file java.exe exists in c:\windows\system32, but the build fails with error code 9009:

```
c:\Windows\System32\java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>operable program or batch file.
1>C:\workspace\Test.csproj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "c:\Windows\System32\java.exe" exited with code 9009.
1>Done building project "Test.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Running java.exe directly from the command line works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, c:\windows\system32 is routed to another path because Visual Studio is a 32 bit application. Using the special alias "Sysnative" works:

```
<Target Name="Java" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="c:\Windows\Sysnative\java.exe"/>
</Target>
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector).